# How to freeze merged columns in data grid view when scrolling vertically?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a data grid view where I need the columns to be frozen or fixed when scrolling vertically.

I have a data grid view control in vb.net windows application which displays the data in a parent-child hierarchy(as shown below). The first column displays the parent data and the second column displays all its child data. The child data in the second column can be as much as 100 rows or even more. So when scrolling down through the grid, the value in the first column does not remain there as it is while the values in the second column(i.e. the child data) scrolls down. So if the user wants to check to which parent, the current child info belongs to, then again he will have to scroll up to the starting of the column to find the name of the parent. I want the values in the first column to be displayed or frozen till it reaches the end of the list of its child values in the grid or at least till the next row where the next parent data starts. I have suggested the client to go with a tree view but they are not agreeing and need it in a data grid view itself. Is there anyway to achieve this in a data grid view?
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: You could use the [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex) to determine the index of the first displayed Row and Paint the content of the cells at `[0, e.RowIndex]` with the name of the Parent, provided that this information is available somewhere in the current datasource (in relation to the current row).

Answer (score 0):

You can't freeze a row (in runtime, on dgv scrolling) with index greater than zero because all those before are frozen and at that point you can't scroll your datagridview.

If I understood correctly what you want I wrote this class quickly (probably should be optimized). Usage is simple.

1 - First create your own datagridview.

2 - then add your columns and rows (IMPORTANT: Put a “X” in the Tag in each row is a Parent or is considered as title for other rows as you seen in TestPopulate method) .

3 - Call the class I made by passing the datagridview (you created first) as a parameter. At this point this control takes its size, placement and REPLACE YOUR DATAGRIDVIEW .

```
  Private Class CustomDgv
    Inherits Panel

    Dim WithEvents TopDgv As DataGridView = New DataGridView
    Dim WithEvents DownDgv As DataGridView = New DataGridView

    Dim Cols As Integer

    ' This variable is in case you have more rows as "headrow"
    ' In TestPopulate you can see how to get those
    Dim listOfOwnerRows As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)

    Dim currentTopRow As Integer = -1

    Protected Overloads Property Height As Integer
        Get
            Return MyBase.Height
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            MyBase.Height = value
            TopDgv.Height = TopDgv.RowTemplate.Height - 1
            DownDgv.Height = value - TopDgv.Height - 1
        End Set
    End Property


    Protected Overloads Property Width As Integer
        Get
            Return MyBase.Width
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            MyBase.Width = value
            TopDgv.Width = value - 1
            DownDgv.Width = value - 1
        End Set
    End Property


    Sub New(dgvOriginal As DataGridView)

        DownDgv = dgvOriginal

        Dim parentCtrl As Control = dgvOriginal.Parent
        parentCtrl.Controls.Remove(dgvOriginal)
        parentCtrl.Controls.Add(Me)

        Me.Location = DownDgv.Location
        Me.Size = DownDgv.Size
        Me.BorderStyle = DownDgv.BorderStyle

        TopDgv.Width = Width - 2 - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth
        TopDgv.Height = TopDgv.RowTemplate.Height
        TopDgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None
        TopDgv.ColumnHeadersVisible = False
        TopDgv.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None

        DownDgv.ColumnHeadersVisible = False
        DownDgv.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None

        TopDgv.Left = 0
        DownDgv.Left = 0
        DownDgv.Width = Width - 2
        DownDgv.Height = Height - 2

        For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In DownDgv.Columns
            Dim cIndex As Integer = TopDgv.Columns.Add(Col.Clone)
            If Col.Frozen Then
                TopDgv.Columns(cIndex).Frozen = True
            End If
            Cols += 1
        Next

        DownDgv.Top = 0

        Me.Controls.Add(TopDgv)
        Me.Controls.Add(DownDgv)


        If DownDgv.Rows.Count > 0 Then

            listOfOwnerRows = (From R As DataGridViewRow In DownDgv.Rows
                               Where R.Tag = "X"
                               Select R.Index).ToList


            If listOfOwnerRows.Count > 0 Then
                SetFrosenRow(listOfOwnerRows(0))
            End If

        End If

    End Sub



    Protected Sub SetFrosenRow(index As Integer)

        If DownDgv.Rows.Count > index Then

            TopDgv.Rows.Clear()
            TopDgv.Rows.Add()

            Dim currentRIndex As Integer = DownDgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex

            'If you want onlly the base row
            For i As Integer = 0 To Cols - 1
                TopDgv.Rows(0).Cells(i).Value = DownDgv.Rows(index).Cells(i).Value
            Next

            'Or else get the diplayed on top row 
            TopDgv.Rows(0).DefaultCellStyle = New DataGridViewCellStyle With {
            .BackColor = Color.Bisque
            }

            currentTopRow = index

        End If

    End Sub


    Protected Sub SetChildValuesInTopRow(index As Integer)
        For i As Integer = 1 To Cols - 1
            TopDgv.Rows(0).Cells(i).Value = DownDgv.Rows(index).Cells(i).Value
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub DownDgv_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles DownDgv.Scroll

        Try

            If e.ScrollOrientation = ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll Then

                Dim topR As Integer = DownDgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex

                'If you want in top row the current value that is in the top uncomment this 
                SetChildValuesInTopRow(topR)

                If listOfOwnerRows.Count > 0 Then

                    Dim rToSetAsOwner As Integer = listOfOwnerRows(listOfOwnerRows.Count - 1)
                    For i As Integer = listOfOwnerRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                        If listOfOwnerRows(i) <= topR Then
                            rToSetAsOwner = listOfOwnerRows(i)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next

                    If rToSetAsOwner <> currentTopRow Then
                        SetFrosenRow(rToSetAsOwner)
                    End If

                    Console.WriteLine("rToSetAsOwner: " & rToSetAsOwner)

                End If

            Else

                TopDgv.HorizontalScrollingOffset = DownDgv.HorizontalScrollingOffset

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub





End Class
```

Usage:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try

        ' first populate you grid putting a tag in each row which is a header/parent/title for other rows
        TestPopulate()

        Dim customControl As Control = New CustomDgv(DataGridView1)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub



Sub TestPopulate()

    For i As Integer = 0 To 100

        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()

        If i = 0 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value = "Owner 0"
            DataGridView1.Rows(0).Tag = "X"
        End If


        If i = 50 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.Item(50).Cells(0).Value = "Owner 50"
            DataGridView1.Rows(50).Tag = "X"
        End If


        If i = 70 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.Item(70).Cells(0).Value = "Owner 70"
            DataGridView1.Rows(70).Tag = "X"
        End If


        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(i).Cells(1).Value = "child_" & i.ToString & "_1"
        DataGridView1.Rows.Item(i).Cells(2).Value = "child_" & i.ToString & "_2"

    Next

End Sub
```

I hope I have been helpful